# sequelize filtering for nested model

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I've been working with sequelize in a couple of weeks, still trying to learn..

My Models are defined in models folder.

**/models/endpoint.js**

```
import Sequelize from 'sequelize';
import { sequelize } from '../data';
import Permission from './permission';

const { Model } = Sequelize;

class Endpoint extends Model { }

Endpoint.init({
  endpoint: {
    type: Sequelize.VIRTUAL(Sequelize.STRING, [ 'method', 'path' ]),
    get() {
      return `${this.get('method')} ${this.get('path')}`;
    }
  },
  method: {
    type: Sequelize.ENUM,
    values: [ 'GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'PATCH' ],
    allowNull: false
  },
  path: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  },
  description: {
    type: Sequelize.TEXT
  }
}, {
  sequelize,
  modelName: 'endpoint'
});

Endpoint.Permissions = Endpoint.hasMany(Permission);
Permission.Endpoint = Permission.belongsTo(Endpoint, { as: 'permission' });

export default Endpoint;
```

**/models/permission.js**

```
import Sequelize from 'sequelize';
import { sequelize } from '../data';

const { Model } = Sequelize;

class Permission extends Model { }

Permission.init({
  entity: {
    type: Sequelize.ENUM,
    values: [ '*', 'user', 'extension', 'queue', 'group' ],
    defaultValue: '*'
  },
  role: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    defaultValue: '*'
  }
}, {
  sequelize,
  modelName: 'permission'
});

export default Permission;
```

found something in docs: [Top level where with eagerly loaded models](https://sequelize.org/v5/manual/models-usage.html#top-level-where-with-eagerly-loaded-models)

```
User.findAll({
    where: {
        '$Instruments.name$': { [Op.iLike]: '%ooth%' }
    },
    include: [{
        model: Tool,
        as: 'Instruments'
    }]
})
```

as following that, I made this

```
Endpoint.findAndCountAll({ 
  where: { 
    path: { [Symbol(iLike)]: '%user%' },
    '$permissions.role$': { [Symbol(eq)]: 'admin' } 
  },
  include: [ 
    { model: permission, as: 'permissions' } 
  ],
  order: [],
  offset: 0,
  limit: 20 
})
```

my code throws this error:

> SequelizeDatabaseError: missing FROM-clause entry for table
>   "permissions"

and generated SQL query:

```
SELECT          "endpoint".*, 
                "permissions"."id"           AS "permissions.id", 
                "permissions"."entity"       AS "permissions.entity", 
                "permissions"."role"         AS "permissions.role", 
                "permissions"."createdAt"    AS "permissions.createdAt", 
                "permissions"."updatedAt"    AS "permissions.updatedAt", 
                "permissions"."endpointId"   AS "permissions.endpointId", 
                "permissions"."permissionId" AS "permissions.permissionId" 
FROM            ( 
                       SELECT "endpoint"."id", 
                              "endpoint"."method", 
                              "endpoint"."path", 
                              "endpoint"."description", 
                              "endpoint"."createdAt", 
                              "endpoint"."updatedAt" 
                       FROM   "endpoints" AS "endpoint" 
                       WHERE  "endpoint"."path" ilike '%user%' 
                       AND    "permissions"."role" = 'admin' limit 20 offset 0) AS "endpoint" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "permissions"                                                   AS "permissions"
ON              "endpoint"."id" = "permissions"."endpointId";
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to use **limit** and **offset** with hasMany associations and with findAndCountAll.

If you have 2 permissions in each endpoint (for instance you have 10 endpoints and set LIMIT to 10) then you'll get first 5 endpoints because in SQL query endpoints will be multiplied with permissions.

If you still want to filter parent records (endpoints) by some conditions on child records then I suppose you need to use sequelize.literal for that purpose.

If you want to filter parent and child records separately (and still use LIMIT and OFFSET) just move the permissions condition clause to association's where clause and also set separate:true in an association include to make LIMIT and OFFSET work correctly (this will make sequelize to execute separate SQL query to get permissions for each endpoint. This latter case will look like this:

```
Endpoint.findAndCountAll({ 
  where: { 
    path: { [Symbol(iLike)]: '%user%' }
  },
  include: [ 
    {
     model: permission,
     as: 'permissions',
     separate: true,
     where: {
       role: { [Symbol(eq)]: 'admin' } 
     }
    } 
  ],
  order: [],
  offset: 0,
  limit: 20 
})
```